# How can I pass a variable in the path

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I have this script and i want to play the song which has the name 'pr_id', how can i write it in the path? Thanks!

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
            var pr_id = document.getElementById('id')
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function (){
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
                        mp3:"/sounds/[pr_id].mp3"
                        });
                        },
                       swfPath: "js", 
                       supplied: "mp3",
                       wmode: "window"
                    });
                });
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "string concatenation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var pr_id = document.getElementById('id');

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { 
                mp3:"/sounds/" + pr_id + ".mp3"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "js", 
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

Concatenate the string with the variable :), unfortunately, unlike some other languages it's not as easy to include variables in string, and you have to split the string up a bit with the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
mp3:"/sounds/"+pr_id+".mp3"
```

you may concatenate it